# Python pymodbus. Как запретить другим программам подключаться к COM-порту, который я использую

Tags: python, com-порт, modbus, порт, pyserial

Я использую библиотеку pymodbus на python для чтения данных по COM-порту. При запуске программа читает данные по COM-порту, но если подключиться к этому же порту какой-то другой программой, то она перехватывает порт и работа моей программы прерывается. Как я могу решить эту проблему и дать компьютеру понять, что порт, который я использую, уже занят и к нему не могут присоединиться другие программы.
Код моего подключения:

```
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port=port, stopbits=2, bytesize=8, parity='N', baudrate=19200, timeout=1)
```

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316722/what-is-the-best-practice-for-locking-serial-ports-and-other-devices-in-linux или тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482327/locking-a-linux-serial-port-or-other-device-in-mono, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980725/locking-linux-serial-port,

Comment: How to open the serial device exclusively in pyserial? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72485792/how-to-open-the-serial-device-exclusively-in-pyserial#:~:text=ser%20%3D%20Serial%20%28port%3Dserialdevice%2C%20baudrate%3D115200%2C%20bytesize%3D8%2C%20timeout%3D2%2C%20exclusive%3DTrue%29,print%20%28e%29%20except%20Exception%20a%20e%3A%20print%20%28e%29

Answer (score 0):

Найдите порт в клиенте (client = ModbusClient...) и заблокируйте его:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600)
ser.lock()
```

Судя по вашему коду

```
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port=port, stopbits=2, bytesize=8, parity='N', baudrate=19200, timeout=1)
```

port и есть искомый объект (хотя может быть и строкой). То есть нужно просто добавить

```
port.lock()
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port=port, stopbits=2, bytesize=8, parity='N', baudrate=19200, timeout=1)
# port.lock() или тут
...
port.unlock()
```